# QT Signals are lost after some time

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, signals, signals-slots

Using C++, Qt 4.8, Google Protobuf 2.4.1
I have a plugin that sends several commands over a port, and these commands are then interpreted in another plugin, which emits the commands as Signals. Upon the reception of each signal a slot is called, which executes a specific task. Each task takes around 1-2 second, to be completed, after which the plugin waits for the second signal in the queue, and runs all over again.

The problem is, if I send quite a few commands eg: 500, not all of them get received (even though they are the same command). The amount of commands that are received is completely random, even if I send the exact same commands, with the exact same parameters.

My question is, is there some sort of a limit as to how many Signals can be queued up? Or is there any time period after which the Signal expires? Or anything that I might be missing?

I am lost and haven't spent too much time using QT...
p.s. the plugin does not crash, or do anything fishy.. it just does not receive any more signals.

Comment: Do you have any timing for sending the commands? Or does the 500 are sent at the same time? What king of connection (auto, direct, queued) do you use for signals/slots ?

Comment: What really happens when a command is processing, and another one arrives? Is it really queued? Does command processing blocks the event loop?

Comment: @BenjaminT the 500 commands get sent all together... the connection type is auto connection

Comment: @vahancho I am not sure how to check if it is really queued.. but the fact that more than one commands get executed everytime, means that they have to be queued. The command processing includes the use of QEventLoop to counter asynchronous effects. Does that matter?

Comment: To me it looks like a network congestion issue rather then Qt. Do you receive 500 commands and are all these 500 commands queued for processing ? From what you describe it looks like when you a process a command the thread is blocked and some commands might be dropped during this blocked thread.

Comment: @deathNode, the fact that some commands got lost can the the root cause of the problem, and not that signals are not sent. Make sure, that all commands received and processed.

Comment: @deathNode Are the signal QObject and the slot QObject in the same thread ? If they are, using AutoConnection is like a direct function call. This means that when the object that emits the signal is blocked for several seconds while the slot completes.

Comment: @BenjaminT Yeah, they are on the same thread. Then you're saying I should handle the signals and slots on a separate thread altogether?

Comment: @deathNode Yes, one thread for getting data from the network as fast as possible and another thread to process the data. This way, if you want to, you can manage the length of the queue and can handle properly cases where you have to much data to process in your queue.

Comment: @BenjaminT alright.. thanks.. let me try that!